# running C script (.h) in linux

Tags: c, sigar

I am trying to run the C libraries from [SIGAR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/sigar/1.6/) API. In the include directory it has few .h files, which i am trying run using below commands. I get "cannot execute binary file", how do i fix it?

```
[oracle@oracleapps include]$ pwd
/home/oracle/sigar/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/sigar-bin/include
[oracle@oracleapps include]$ cc -o test sigar_fileinfo.h
[oracle@oracleapps include]$ ./test
-bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file
[oracle@oracleapps include]$
```

Comment: i am not familiar with sigar, but generally .h files are meant to be included in your code , not compiled and executed by themselves.

Comment: And libraries also don't run by themselves, they're meant to be linked into applications that you write. The header files are used to provide the declarations so that the functions will be recognized and called properly.

Comment: That file [sigar_fileinfo.h](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/master/include/sigar_fileinfo.h) contains information for C programs that intend to use the SIGAR library. Are you sure you know what to do with `.h` files?

Comment: @Blastfurnace can you give me simple example how to run anything of the file in sigar api?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Do you know how to write `C` programs? Do you know any of the other languages SIGAR supports (Java, Perl, Ruby, Python, Erlang, PHP and C#)? Did you read the [documentation](http://sigar.hyperic.com/)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SIGAR and you don't know `C` so this is beyond the scope of what I can do with my spare time here on SO. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that i cannot compile .h files, hence i wrote another .c program and called the c libraries. This have resolved my issue